# Wait until all threads complete before running next task

Tags: multithreading, powershell, jobs, start-job

I would wrap everything inside `foreach($computer in $computers)` in a `Start-Job` to make them run simultaneously. The only problem is, I need to wait for all the jobs to complete before I do the `ConvertTo-Json` at the bottom.

```
$sb = "OU=some,OU=ou,DC=some,DC=domain"
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true)} -SearchBase "$sb" -Properties *
$hasmanufacturer = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
foreach($computer in $computers)
{
    $drives = try{@(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive -Property * -ComputerName $computer.Name -ErrorAction Stop)} catch {$null}
    foreach($drive in $drives)
    {
        if($drive.Manufacturer)
        {
            $hasmanufacturer.Add($computer)
            continue
        }
    } # inner foreach
}

ConvertTo-Json $hasmanufacturer
```

Comment: Unrelated, but ... why are you using `-ErrorAction Stop` when you return `$null` in case of an error? Removing the `try..catch` and `@()` and using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` instead should have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`Get-Job | Wait-Job`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) before executing the `ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: The foreach will create X number of jobs (depending on the length of `$computers`. I thought `Wait-Job` only waits for one of them?

Comment: @KolobCanyon Perhaps on its own, but not combined with `Get-Job` as this passes the running jobs to it :-). Check out Example 1 in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the array of computer names as a parameter to `Invoke-Command`. It will run, by default, 32 concurrent remote sessions. The number can be changed with the `-Throttle` parameter.

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(Enabled -eq $true)} -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=xxx,DC=com" -Properties Name |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'LAX_*' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Name }

$computers

$j = Invoke-Command `
    -ComputerName $computers `
    -ScriptBlock { Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_CDROMDrive -Property * -ErrorAction Stop } `
    -AsJob

while ( (Get-Job -Id $j.Id).Status -eq 'Running') {}

Get-Job -Id $j.Id | Wait-Job

$results = Receive-Job -Id $j.Id
$results
```